# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.feature_extraction.dict_vectorizer'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to preprocess a bengali dataset using BLTK. But, it gives me an error. I dont know why. I have sci-kit learn installed and updated it.
This is my code:

```
from bltk.langtools import remove_stopwords
from bltk.langtools import Tokenizer
from bltk.langtools import UgraStemmer
from bltk.langtools import PosTagger
import re

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
stemmer = UgraStemmer()


corpus = []
y_val = []
for i in range(0, len(messages)):
    review = messages['text'][i]
    y_val_temp = messages['Class'][i]
    review = "".join(i for i in review if i in ["।"] or 2432 <= ord(i) <= 2559 or ord(i)== 32)
    review =" ".join(review.split())
    
    review = tokenizer.word_tokenizer(review)
    #print(review)
    while("" in review) : 
        review.remove("") 
    review = remove_stopwords(review, level='hard')
    #print(review)
    review = stemmer.stem(review)
    #print(review)
    if(review==None):
        continue
    review = ' '.join(review)
    
    corpus.append(review)
    y_val.append(y_val_temp)
```

The error shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11864/3574551415.py in <module>
      6 
      7 tokenizer = Tokenizer()
----> 8 stemmer = UgraStemmer()
      9 
     10 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bltk\langtools\stemmer.py in __init__(self)
      5 class UgraStemmer:
      6     def __init__(self):
----> 7         self.pos_tagger = PosTagger()
      8         self.pronoun_values = list(pronouns.values())
      9         self.pronoun_keys = list(pronouns.keys())

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bltk\langtools\pos_tagger.py in __init__(self)
     10 class PosTagger:
     11     def __init__(self):
---> 12         self.data = PosTagger.get_data()
     13 
     14     @staticmethod

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bltk\langtools\pos_tagger.py in get_data()
     15     def get_data():
     16         with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "..//data//pos_tagger.pkl"), "rb") as tagger:
---> 17             pos_tagger = pickle.load(tagger)
     18             return pos_tagger
     19 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.feature_extraction.dict_vectorizer'
```

I dont know why is this error occuring. I started doing ml few days back. so, I will appreciate if you anyone answer it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few warnings before we proceed. (1) The error is raised from `pickle.load`. The [Python documentation has a big warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) that says roughly "pickle is not secure, only unpickle data you trust." We should be extremely cautious here, at best this package doesn't follow standard practice; at worst it's actively malicious. (2) `bltk` [has three commits](https://github.com/saimoncse19/bltk) on GitHub, and does not appear to have been updated in ~2 years, so it may be abandoned software.

Comment: After downloading, the `pos_tagger.pkl` appears to contain 20.9 MB of arbitrary Python data. The `ModuleNotFoundError` suggests that it found a copy of `scikit-learn`, but did not find the `dict_vectorizer`. This *might* imply that the pickle file was serialized with an incompatible version of scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio code editor, try and go to the search bar (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) and write: `developer:reload window` and refresh. It's a bug in VS code if you're using that.

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook